# Using Databases in C++ and Visual Studio 6

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio

I already did some searching on stackoverflow and as far as I can see there are many ways to use databases in C++. Unfortunately at work my tools are pretty limited. I only get to use visual studio C++ 6 and don't even have boost (although I have learned to cope with that) - I assume that I can only use what is the standard distribution being delivered togather with VS C++ 6.

Now my code generates a lot of data and I would like to store some of it in a simple databse (like an MS Access db). What tools might I be able to use?

My alternative approauch would be to create a database-like object via a struct and vectors/arrays.

I also have office 2010 installed - perhaps I could somehow use Access?

Computation-speed also plays a role - the faster the better.

> > **Another important thing:** my PC at work isn't an open client. Thus I can not install any new software. Downloading and moving files works. Basically I must be able to install the tool by just moving the files into a desired folder.

Please let me know if the question is confusing or insufficiently detailed I will do what i can to remedy the situation then.

Thnaks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Why can't you use a modern compiler?

Comment: my employer does not want to spent money on one. I am happy to finally have excel 2010 installed - the 256 column limitation was killing me. Long story short - getting a new compiler would be outstandingly difficult for then all the other employees coding in C (most cant do C++) will need one two

Comment: what about express version of visual studio?

Comment: Haven't you guys ever worked in extra-secure institutions? It takes months to get anything approved to be installed on your machine. Forget it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you said 'only standard tools', I'd still  say, get SQLite. It ss a public domain software, i.e. **no license whatsoever** . You can download an 'amalgamation' - one .h file and one .c file and include it into your project. It should compile in VC6 no problem. Very easy to use, you will be up and running in 10 minutes.

It does exactly what you need - a DB in a single file, no servers, zero-setup, etc.

Comment: I am not an open client - basically I can not install any software without getting a permission from the IT-security department first (as you might know a tedius and relly long lasting process). Things like portable apps work - so basically if I only have to include some .h and .cpp files it should work.

Comment: Do I actually need to install anything or does it suffice to move the data in a certain folder and include some headers? SQLite looks very promissing :)

Comment: you don't need to install -any-thing- just include `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.c` files into your project an you are ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Visual C++ 6 did include [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) which had a suite of classes for the creation and manipulation of [databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dhc1abk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), I'm fairly certain it would be possible to use these to create a database that is accessible from Access. Unfortunately Microsoft's online help doesn't seem to go back that far, but all the reference material you need should come with the VS 6. (In my opinion VS Help system was better back then anyways.)

On a side note, you could download an [old version of boost](http://www.boost.org/users/history/) that would work with VS6. I'm not sure what the last version of boost that supports VS6 is, my guess it's somewhere around 1.3x.

Answer (score 1):

VC6 should work.

Can you use MFC's db objects? (DAO I think back then?).

If your app really generates *a lot* of data, you might want to look at MySql. I've run into size limitations in older Access tables. Unless it's an extraordinarily simple db, you probably don't want to brew your own (though it might be fun if you have a lot of time).

The key will be finding a driver/db combo that will work. I would install the GA (free) MySql, create a tiny db with 1 table and find the driver ("connector" in MySql terms) that will work. Maybe older ODBC driver?

Also, check out [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for info on getting connected to a particular database / driver.